# reverse relation in postgres

Tags: typescript, postgresql, reverse, typeorm

I have table in my database "textDate"

```
class TextData extends BaseEntity{
 
id(primaryGeneratedColumn)

ar:string

en:string

}
```

this entity is used to store all text in my project like title, description and other fields have foreign key to it

```
class object extends baseEntity{

id

@OneToOne()
@joinColumn()
title:TextData
...
```

I need to search in text data and get record from it due to some conditions and i want to get the object which has Fk to this textData record
**note**: there is several type of objects have access to text data object1(title),car(title),career(title)
all of them have fk to text data...
is there any thing to do?
I Made

```
 select 'post' as Type,p3 .id 
from post p3  
where p3."tagsId" =any ('{1,2,3}') or p3."titleId" =any ('{1,2,3}') 
 join text_data td 
 on td.id =p3."titleId" as  titil
UNION  
select 'career' as Type,c2 .id 
from career c2 
join text_data td 
 on td.id =c2."titleId" as  titil
where c2."tagsId" =any ('{1,2,3}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save a reference to the child table in text_data, like the name of the child table.

Your query has some mistakes:

```
select 'post' as Type, p3.id 
from post p3  
join text_data td on td.id = p3."titleId"
where p3."tagsId" = any('{1,2,3}') or p3."titleId" = any('{1,2,3}')

UNION  

select 'career' as Type, c2.id 
from career c2 
join text_data td on td.id = c2."titleId" 
where c2."tagsId" = any('{1,2,3}')
```

Another way to do the query:

```
SELECT td.id, coalesce(p3.type, c2.type) AS type

FROM text_data td

INNER JOIN (SELECT "titleId", 'post' AS type FROM post WHERE "tagsId" = any('{1,2,3}') or "titleId" = any('{1,2,3}')) AS p3 ON td.id = p3."titleId"

INNER JOIN (SELECT "titleId", 'career' AS type FROM career WHERE "tagsId" = any('{1,2,3}')) AS c2 ON td.id = c2."titleId"
```